# SFMC - upload contents (as a formatted JSON) to sftp

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

Let's say we've got `<input type="file">` inside a form placed on a cloudpage
and posted it using POST with our file contents as a form params to a server side.
Is it possible to send our payload to known `sftp endpoint` directly from form handler somehow (we have already got some logic to be good enough with)?
Or there is a need to utilize some middleware solution?